# How the hashnode constructor gets Initialized

Tags: c++, constructor

I am trying to implement hashing using seperate chaining. I am not able to understand how the `hashnode` constructor gets initialized though we are only constructing object for class `hashmap`. They both are private to each other and also I have not derived class `hashmap` from `hashnode`. So how does that work?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
static const int table_size = 10;
class hashnode {
        public:
            int key;
            int value;
            hashnode* next;

            hashnode(int key, int value)
            {
                this->key = key;
                this->value = value;
                this->next = NULL;
            }

};

class hashmap {
    hashnode** table;
public:
    hashmap()
    {
        table = new hashnode* [table_size];
        for(int i=0;i<table_size;i++)
        {
            table[i] = NULL; 
        }
    }

    int hash(int key)
    {
        return key%table_size;
    }

    void insert(int key, int value)
    {
        int hash_val = hash(key);
        hashnode* prev = NULL;
        hashnode* entry = table[hash_val];

        while(entry != NULL)
        {
            prev = entry;
            entry = entry->next;
        }

        if(entry == NULL)
        {
            entry = new hashnode(key,value);
            if(prev == NULL)
            {
                table[hash_val] = entry;
            }
            else
            {
                prev->next = entry;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            entry->value = value;
        }
    }

    void printtable(int key)
    {
         while(table[0] != NULL)
         {
            cout<<table[0]->key<<endl;
            table[0] = table[0]->next;
         }
    }  
};

int main()
{
hashmap hash1;
int key,value;
int choice;
```

Comment: If the "array" `hashmap::table` has a fixed compile-time size, why not use an actual array? And if the size isn't actually a compile-time constant, you should probably be using `std::vector` instead.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg probably because that thing will eventually expand via academia-driven task and everything rehashed once the load factor is exceeded. At least that's why I would do it. (ok, that was a lie, I'd just use `std::unordered_map<>` as would nearly everyone else I suspect).

Comment: As for your problem, I don't really understand it. The `hashnode` class only have `public` members (almost making it a `struct`), so there's no problem creating instances of it anywhere. And the `hashnode` class doesn't have any references back to the `hashmap` class. And you do create instances of the `hashnode` class, and initializes those instances by (indirectly) calling the constructor when you do `new hashnode(..)`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg If you could help me with a better implementation that would be a great help.

Comment: What he's saying is your statement "we are only constructing object for class hashmap" is *not true*. What do you think `new hashnode(key,value);` *does*, if not dynamically allocate and construct a new `hasnnode` ? And regarding alternative implementation, your `insert` member could be [considerably more brief](http://pastebin.com/vs03rsG1).

Comment: hashmap has hashnode** table field, which is dynamic array of *hashnode; on other note, there's no destructor for hashmap, should implement it to prevent memory leak

Comment: @jonezq thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `table = new hashnode* [table_size];` **is** calling the constructor for `hashnode`. That's what `new` does; it allocates space for each object and then calls the object's constructor.

You're asking for the compiler to create 10 (based on `table_size`) `hashnode` objects.